# Opencart show discount price in product featured page

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to the `opencart`. I have setup featured product in my homepage. So when one will visit he can see all the featured product with its description. Now here in this featured page I have shown the product price by using `<?php echo $product['price']; ?>`. It is showing the product price without any problem.
Now I want to show the product discounts in the featured page. So how to do that? Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: before doing any down vote any suggestions and advice will be more helpful.

Comment: What have You tried? Product discount is stored in `$product['special']` as OpenCart differs between **discounts** (if You buy 5 pcs the price get discounted, if You buy 10 pcs it is discounted even more, etc) and **specials** - price special discounts for a limited time. This special is present in all the modules displaying boxes with products, even in **featured** module. Probably You played with the template and removed that piece of code...

Answer (score 3):

Untested, but should work in theory.

**First, in `catalog/language/english/module/featured.php` add the following line:**

```
$_['text_discount']     = '%s or more %s';
```

**Next, in `catalog/controller/module/featured.php` do the following:**

After `$this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');` add:

```
$this->data['text_discount'] = $this->language->get('text_discount');
```

After `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);` add:

```
$discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($product_id);
$product_discounts[] = array(); 

foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
    $product_discounts[] = array(
        'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
        'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))
    );
}
```

After `'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),` add:

```
'discounts'  => $product_discounts
```

**Finally, in `catalog/view/theme/<theme>/template/module/featured.tpl` add this wherever you want it to display:**

```
<?php foreach ($product['discounts'] as $discount) { ?>
<?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I want the discount prices not the actual price here.I have already got the price in featured template but now I want the product discounted prices which can be seen in product details page. That I want to show in featured products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is showing error like ` Undefined index: quantity` in `catalog/view/theme/<theme>/template/module/featured.tpl`

Comment: when I used your total codes and made `print_r($discounts);` inside  `/catlog/controller/module` then the reault was like this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_discount_id] => 483 [product_id] => 43 [customer_group_id] => 8 [quantity] => 2 [priority] => 1 [price] => 345.0000 [date_start] => 0000-00-00 [date_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [1] => Array ( [product_discount_id]  ) ) `

Comment: I'll try to test the above code on my development server tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Haven't managed to get time to test - looking at the above array, it is building one array properly and the second array has it's elements missing - how many discounts do you have for the product?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, in catalog/view/theme//template/module/featured.tpl add this wherever you want it to display:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlXDM.jpg)